# Turning a list of string values into a list of integers for the length of those strings

Tags: python

I though this would be fairly easy, basically running like

```
table2[x][y] = len(table1[x][y])
```

But I can't seem to work out the ranges.  The code below comes out with a -

> IndexError: list index out of range

No matter how I alter the ranges. Any thoughts?

```
#Replace string values in a list of lists with the length of the string

table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

new_table_data = {}

new_table = []

def string_to_length(message):
    global new_table
    for x in range(len(message)):
        b = 0
        while b < len(message[0]):
            new_table[x][b] = (len(message[x][b]))
            #print(x)
            #print(' ' + str(b))
            b = b+1
    print(new_table)

string_to_length(table_data)
```

Comment: List comprehension is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(table_data)):
  for j in range(len(table_data[i])):
    table_data[i][j] = len(table_data[i][j])
```

## There you go.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like: (using nested list comprehension)

```
print [[len(i) for i in element] for element in table_data ]
```

Or, (using map and list comprehension)

```
print [map(len,element) for element in table_data]
```

For the input:

```
table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
         ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

Output:

```
[[6, 7, 8, 6], [5, 3, 5, 5], [4, 4, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  The book has not given me list comprehension functions yet.

Comment: Do you think you could explain why my code does not work?  x cycles through 0,1,2 and b cycles through 0,1,2,3.  Why would there be a range error?

Answer (score 0):

```
table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
         ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
new_table = []

def string_to_length(message):
global new_table
for x in range(len(message)):
    b = 0
    sub_table =[]  # create an empty subarray
    while b < len(message[0]):
        # python is not like C so u can not directly access index by index
        sub_table.append (len(message[x][b])) # append len value
        b = b+1
    new_table.append(sub_table) # append the subtable to new_table
#print(new_table)

string_to_length(table_data)

print new_table
```

Comment: Also very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. When I learnt python after learning C, I am considering python as C. It is most common but mistake.